# Appium on ios actual device gives sdk iphone simulator error

Tags: ios, selenium, appium

Friends,
Trying to run appium script on ios actual device,gets below error

Eclipse error:

> [TestNG] Running:
>
> /private/var/folders/05/79kfthm94qjd3bngd2l5pv7r0mx69v/T/testng-eclipse--1690789728/testng-customsuite.xml
>
> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUpBeforeClass
>
> **org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could
>   not be  created. (Original error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c xcrun
>   --sdk iphonesimulator  --show-sdk-version)** (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>
> Command duration or timeout: 15.00 seconds
>
> Build info: version: '2.51.0', revision: '1af067d', time:
>   '2016-02-05  19:15:17'
>
> System info: host: 'NCA047065', ip: '10.65.210.61', os.name: 'Mac
>   OS X',   os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.5', java.version:
>   '1.7.0_79'
>
> Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver

And .java code:

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class iOSApptest {

public static RemoteWebDriver driver;


@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception
{ 
    File appDir = new File ("//Users//gangaiahl//Appium//jars");
    File app = new File (appDir, "Car.ipa");

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "firefox");
    capabilities.setCapability("device", "iPhone 6");
    capabilities.setCapability("u_did", "840384833537f40d011032eaaf20a53705a451ce");
    capabilities.setCapability("bundle_id", "au.dev.com.onewaytraffic.carsguide");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Cars_iPhone_6");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.2"); 
    capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

@Test
public void test()
{
    System.out.println("Test started");
    //System.out.println(" Start to identify a test");
    //System.out.println("Test Completed");
}
```

}

Comment: i hope your simulator is running other than these tests as well

Comment: Why you are using RemoteDriver use IOSDriver is there any reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems wrong capability

> capabilities.setCapability("u_did",
>   "840384833537f40d011032eaaf20a53705a451ce");

Try use "udid" key instead of "u_did"

See [documentation](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#ios-only)

Answer (score 1):

You can try since that could have to do with the libxml library according to a quick google search.

```
$ brew uninstall libxml2
$ brew prune
$ brew install libxml2
```

You should also try and update your Xcode command line tools. Since its failing when trying to use the xcrun command.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 11**

Try installing command-line tools from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ 
This solved my error